# Passing string from ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, exception

I'm struggling with mapping the Constraint violation exception. I wanted to write my own message when the method call exception eg. "Exception caused by :name" and pass the name in string form in try-catch. There's no constructor that have only string in it. I'm already using mapper class that overrides Response to pass custom message.

So, i have a method sth like
`public Data addData(final Data newData) {
dbService.sth(persist(newData)); 
return getData(newData.getName());}`
and want to add try-catch and throw new ConstraintViolationException that gives messega like "Data already exist :newData". In other methods i have sth like
`try {
return dbService //query here to select data } 
catch (NoResultException e) { throw new NoResultException("Data not found :name"); }`

And ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper that overrides Response, logs error and returns new response.

Comment: Your question is very vague and unclear. Can you please update this question with as much accurate details as possible for us to help you?

Comment: You could try posting your current code and we'll try to fix it :)

Comment: You could probably use [ConstraintViolationException(String, Set)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html#ConstraintViolationException%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%29) and use an empty or null `Set` (or simply define your constraints that where violated.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi  edited first post, now i hope its clear